# Plugin localization persistance (woocommerce)

Tags: translation, localization

I am having an issue with a WooCommerce translation being overwritten.

What I've tried so far:

- moving my `woocommerce-de_DE.po/mo` files to `wp-content/languages/plugins/`
- blocking translation auto-updates with `add_filter( 'auto_update_translation', '__return_false' );`
- setting the po/mo files permissions to 444
  None of those worked, and I am having troubles identifying the cause of the problem.

Do you have any suggestions?

PS: maybe relevant: I have `Loco translate` installed (I'm using it for translating other plugins and my theme) but for WooCommerce I'm uploading my po/mo files directly to the languages/plugin folder)

Answer (score 0):

444 would not stop a file being deleted. Deletion observes the permissions of the containing directory only. Whether the file is writable is irrelevant, because you're not writing to it.

Other people have posted they results using the filter approach. I suggest you have a look through their follow ups.

Please note that 1.x version of this plugin is being phased out. If you have any issues please consider beta testing version 2.

The new version allows you to save files under wp-content/languages/loco/ - thus avoiding auto update overwrites. You can also configure the new version to use custom folders, such as woocommerce's wp-content/languages/woocommerce/ path